# Exchange data between google-glass and a android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass

The scenario:

I have a android app running my in cellphone. I´m the owner of this app.
I have a google-glass synced with this cellphone. I´m developing a my app for google-glass using the new GDK launch a few weeks ago.

I want to send a data from glass to cellphone and then receive a answer.
No internet connection is necessary, so i´m planning to use Bluetooth to this data communication.

I can create a Bluetooth socket connection, however this will obligate me to manage it.
There is no android high level abstraction that permit me to call a service or a activity directly on the cellphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no direct pipe between them, the glass is basically a phone with a different set of inputs and outputs. You can create and manage the connection, and it's yours.

Comment: I'd like to add, I wish there were some high-level abstraction as you've described. It would be awesome if I could broadcast from one to the other, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no other way to do this, as Travis said there's no  direct pipeline between them, seems to be true. You can use use BLUETOOTH Chat Application included in the Android SDK.

> 1. Just change the input method to voice input in the application
> 2. Install that Application in both the devices
> 3. Try It

change the code accordingly to send files too.

Comment: I have tested a bluetooth data send/receive from and to glass and phone and it works...so +1 for suggesting this...