# Google GDK and Bluetooth discoverable intent

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-glass, google-gdk

I'm making an app to send datas to my Google Glasses from my smartphone via Bluetooth. I've followed this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609745/exchange-data-between-google-glass-and-a-android-device) (same scenario) and tried the following. This is running on the Google Glasses :

```
Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE); 
discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 120);
startActivity(discoverableIntent);
```

But I get this error :

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.glass/com.example.MainActivity}: 
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { 
act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE (has extras)` }
```

I've set up the permissions for using Bluetooth on my Manifest this way :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

There is already an unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820680/google-glass-gdk-bluetooth-discoverable-intent). I've found an [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336968/google-glass-gdk-how-to-communicate-with-android-device) to it, but it doesn't explains me why this error occurs. Any ideas ?